# Configurable Products - update price by selected simple product

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1

I#m building up an store based on Magento CE1.9.1 with configurable products. In the past there were Extensions like Simple Configurable Product and Better Configurable Product, but SCP isn't up to date and BCP doesn't work with HTML5-Themes.

Do anyone of you know how it is possible (or is there another extension) to update the product price depending on the selected simple product price?

Is it possible to select the default simple product on configurable product?

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use the price of the associated simple product, there are a few extensions out there:

- [OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple): As you said, it is not up-to-date and not supported any more, so I would not really recommend using that.
- [BCP - Better Configurable Products](http://de.nr-apps.com/store/bcp-better-configurable-products.html): I am sure this works in any template, though you may have to do some little modifications of your template. Unfortunately, it is not available any more.
- [Ayasoftware Simple Product Pricing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-product-pricing.html): To be honest, we were not really satisfied with the code quality.
- [Best4Mage Configurable Products Use Simple Price & Details](https://www.best4mage.com/configurable-products-use-simple-price.html): To be honest, we were not really satisfied with the code quality.
- [magehub Configurable Products To Use Simple Price](https://www.magehubextensions.com/configurable-products-to-use-simple-price.html): I did not use that one yet.

But another option comes for free with Magento - may be this is enough for you. If you edit the configurable product, under the associated products tab, you can enter surcharges for each associated simple product:

[image: Surcharges for Associated Simple Products]

The price will then be the price of the configurable product plus the entered surcharge.